# Creating a cluster with two laptops (mac)

Tags: gpu, cluster-computing, ray

I’m new to Ray and wondering if the usecase below works with Ray.
I have two laptops (mac) and want to utilize these gpus to create a ray gpu cluster. I want to put one mac parent node and the other one worker node connected to the parent node. Is this feasible?